# preg_match special characters

Tags: php

How can I use `preg_match` to see if special characters `` [^'£$%^&*()}{@:'#~?><>,;@|\-=-_+-¬`] `` exist in a string?

Comment: Define "special characters"...

Comment: [^'£$%^&*()}{@:'#~?><>,;@|\-=-_+-¬`]

Comment: Why do you want to use `preg_match()`? If all you're doing is checking for the existence of these characters, why not use `strpos()`?

Comment: If your input is ASCII characters then you could just check by the character integer ranges.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`[\W]+` will match any non-word character.

but to match only the characters from the question, use this:

```
  $string="sadw$"
  if(preg_match("/[\[^\'£$%^&*()}{@:\'#~?><>,;@\|\\\-=\-_+\-¬\`\]]/", $string)){
   //this string contain atleast one of these [^'£$%^&*()}{@:'#~?><>,;@|\-=-_+-¬`] characters
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but i need only specific characters like ^'£$%^&*()}{@:'#~?><>,;@|\-=-_+-¬`

Comment: Normally I'd say `[\W]` is still perfect for you, as a "word character" refers to any letter, number, or underscore and excludes just about everything else. I'm not sure if it includes hyphen. Then I noticed underscore was in the list of characters you want to check for. Since you only want to find single characters it may be quicker to use `explode()` and `in_array()` instead of `preg_match()`, or just use a `while()` loop. Although neither of these are very intuitive.

Comment: What if the string contains Unicode character? Your regex excludes them!

Comment: [\W] includes `#`

Comment: @d.raev that is expected for it to include # as a non-word character

Answer (score 13):

Use [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php). This function takes in a regular expression (pattern) and the subject string and returns `1` if match occurred, `0` if no match, or `false` if an error occurred.

```
$input = 'foo';
$pattern = '/[\'\/~`\!@#\$%\^&\*\(\)_\-\+=\{\}\[\]\|;:"\<\>,\.\?\\\]/';

if (preg_match($pattern, $input)){
    // one or more matches occurred, i.e. a special character exists in $input
}
```

---

You may also specify flags and offset for the *Perform a Regular Expression Match* function. See the documentation link above.

Comment: Is there any reference/link for individual symbols?

Answer (score 10):

My function makes life easier.

```
function has_specchar($x,$excludes=array()){
    if (is_array($excludes)&&!empty($excludes)) {
        foreach ($excludes as $exclude) {
            $x=str_replace($exclude,'',$x);        
        }    
    }    
    if (preg_match('/[^a-z0-9 ]+/i',$x)) {
        return true;        
    }
    return false;
}
```

The second parameter ($excludes) may be passed with values you wish to ignore.

Usage

```
$string = 'testing_123';
if (has_specchar($string)) { 
    // special characters found
} 

$string = 'testing_123';
$excludes = array('_');
if (has_specchar($string,$excludes)) { } // false
```

Answer (score 2):

For me, this works best:

```
$string = 'Test String';

$blacklistChars = '"%\'*;<>?^`{|}~/\\#=&';

$pattern = preg_quote($blacklistChars, '/');
if (preg_match('/[' . $pattern . ']/', $string)) {
   // string contains one or more of the characters in var $blacklistChars
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `preg_quote` to escape charaters to use inside a regex expression:

```
preg_match('/' . preg_quote("[^'£$%^&*()}{@:'#~?><>,;@|\-=-_+-¬`]", '/') . '/', $string);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php

Answer (score 0):

This works well for all PHP versions. The resultant is a bool and needs to be used accordingly.

To check id the string contains characters you can use this:

`preg_match( '/[a-zA-Z]/', $string );`

To check if a string contains numbers you can use this.

`preg_match( '/\d/', $string );`

Now to check if a string contains special characters, this one should be used.

`preg_match('/[^a-zA-Z\d]/', $string);`

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to match on special characters

```
preg_match('/[\'\/~`\!@#\$%\^&\*\(\)_\-\+=\{\}\[\]\|;:"\<\>,\.\?\\\]/', $input)
```