# how to check for special characters php

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [preg_match php special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937569/preg-match-php-special-characters)

Hi all, I want to check if these characters exist in a string by using `preg_match`:

`^'£$%^&*()}{@'#~?><>,@|\-=-_+-¬'`

Help please!

Comment: Same as your previous question: [preg_match php special characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937569/preg-match-php-special-characters)

Comment: why do you need to check them?

Comment: Please edit old questions, don't repost.

Comment: Btw, "white-list strategy" is more efficient and "correct": in this case you need to check if all characters are in allowed set.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

```
<?php

$string = 'foo';

if (preg_match('/[\'^£$%&*()}{@#~?><>,|=_+¬-]/', $string))
{
    // one or more of the 'special characters' found in $string
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to get the position of the special characters?

Comment: It's pretty obvious and he commented the explaination inside the code.

Comment: This example does not seem to work, I have tested here : http://phptester.net/ and on my xampp server and get FATAL ERROR syntax error, unexpected '$', expecting ')' on line number 5

Comment: There is a duplicate in the pattern ">"

Answer (score 10):

`preg_match('/'.preg_quote('^\'£$%^&*()}{@#~?><,@|-=-_+-¬', '/').'/', $string);`

Comment: Didn't realize that `preg_quote` was an available function. May be useful to some.