# Message : undefine Offset : 10 from codeigniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, foreach

I Have Problem function **for** in controller, form more code like bellow :

i send data **iddata** with ajax to controller "Update_Kebutuhan_ke_Terpasang"

```
http://localhost/gishubkbm/Terpasang/Update_Kebutuhan_ke_Terpasang?iddata=[1,2,16,15,17,3,14,5,9,11]
```

code in Controller like bellow :

```
$iddata=array();
$iddata=array($_GET['iddata']); //value [1,2,16,15,17,3,14,5,9,11]
$a=explode(",", $iddata[0]); //explode value iddata
$b=preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $a);
$jumlahdata=count($b);
for($i=0;$i<=$jumlahdata;$i++)
{
    $c=$b[$i]; // **problem here with message undefined offset : 10**
    $data=array('id_perjal'=>$c);
    $this->M_perjal_terpasang->save($data);
}
echo json_encode(array("status" => TRUE));
```

but all Proses run, data can input on database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More than one things need to change. Check the comments and code like below:-

```
$iddata=array();
//$iddata=array($_GET['iddata']); //value [1,2,16,15,17,3,14,5,9,11]   this line not needed
$a=explode(",", $_GET['iddata']); //explode whole $_GET['iddata']

$jumlahdata=count($a); // count the length
for($i=0;$i<$jumlahdata;$i++) // remove = to sign so that it iterates only 10 times from 0 to 9
{
    if(!empty($a[$i])){ // still check variable is set and have value
        $b=preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $a[$i]); // do the replacement here on each array value,not just one outside
        $c=$b;
        $data=array('id_perjal'=>$c);
        $this->M_perjal_terpasang->save($data);
    }
}
echo json_encode(array("status" => TRUE));
```

Answer (score 2):

You're over iterating

Since arrays are 0-indexed in PHP, an array containing 10 elements doesn't have an element with an index of 10 - the final index is 9.

Your `for` loop should only iterate `$i` when it's *less than* the number of elements, **not** *less than or equal to*:

Change:

```
for($i = 0; $i <= $jumlahdata; $i++)
{
    $c=$b[$i]; // **problem here with message undefined offset : 10**
}
```

to:

```
for($i = 0; $i < $jumlahdata; $i++)
{
    $c=$b[$i]; // **problem here with message undefined offset : 10**
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When i run you code i got few erros.

1. `$a=explode(",", $iddata[0]);` in this point only one data returning
2. `$b=preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $a);` no ide what you mean by this...

---

Final **working code** for you

```
$b=array();
$b=array(1,2,16,15,17,3,14,5,9,11); # assume your array

foreach($b as $item)
{
    echo $item; # this will print all in a row.
    //$data=array('id_perjal'=>$item);
    //$this->M_perjal_terpasang->save($data);
}
```

---

> if you use `empty()` its always true, Cz you're not fixing the actual error

---

This might help full for you

1. [how to check for special characters php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3938021/how-to-check-for-special-characters-php)