# Checking for special characters

Tags: php, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [preg_match php special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937569/preg-match-php-special-characters)

As part of my register system I need to check for the existence of special characters In an variable. How can I perform this check? The person who gives the most precise answer gets best.

Comment: If you want ppl to help you, the pls accept anwsers to your previous questions.

Comment: The definition of "special characters" is subject to interpretation. Can you define what you mean by "special characters"? Or perhaps which characters you don't consider "special characters" if that list is shorter?

Comment: What do u mean by " person who gives the most precise answer gets best." This is a community, not a contest.

Comment: I mean characters such as !"£$%^&&*-/ and whatnot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$special_chars = // all the special characters you want to check for 
$string = // the string you want to check for 

if (preg_match('/'.$special_chars.'/', $string))
{
// special characters exist in the string.
}
```

Check the manual of [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.preg-match.php) for more details

Comment: ah yeah, if you want to check for the existance rather than escape the special chars, this is the way to go

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you mean html entities when you say "special chars", you can use this:

```
<?php
$table = get_html_translation_table(HTML_ENTITIES, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
$chars = implode('', array_keys($table));

if (preg_match("/[{$chars}]+/", $string) === 1) {
    // special chars in string
}
```

[`get_html_translation_table`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-html-translation-table.php) gets all the possible html entities.  If you only want the entities that the function [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) converts, then you can pass `HTML_SPECIALCHARS` instead of `HTML_ENTITIES`.  The return value of `get_html_translation_table` is an array of (html entity, escaped entity) pairs.

Next, we want to put all the html entities in a regular expression like `[&"']+`, which will match any substring containing one of the characters inside square brackets of length 1 or more.  So we use [`array_keys`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) to get the keys of the translation table (the unencoded html entities), and implode them together into a single string.

Then we put them into the regular expression and use [`preg_match`](http://php.net/preg_match) to see if the string contains any of those characters.  You can read more about [regular expression syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php) at the PHP docs.

Answer (score 0):

A quick google search for "php special characters" brings up some good info:

```
htmlentities() - http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

htmlspecialchars() - http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php
```

Comment: I think you need to read the manuals yourselves once. These are used for converting all characters to HTML entities and not checking if special characters exist

Comment: check-out my comment on your post